# Objective-C: instance variable as a parameter, but after method call instance variable is empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I do some iOS programming stuff and I have a `UIViewController` with a `NSMutableArray`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* mutableTestArray;
...
@synthesize mutableTestArray;
```

In `viewDidLoad` I want to call a method which is inside the implementation of this `UIViewController`:

```
//- (void)aTestMethod:(NSMutableArray *)myMutableTestArray;
[self aTestMethod:self.mutableTestArray];
```

So I call the method with a `NSMutableArray` which is an instance variable of the `UIViewController`. Inside this method, I do this:

```
myMutableTestArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
//... looping & generating some objects and adding them to the array:
[myMutableTestArray adObject:myObject];
```

Now, I debug it and inside the method `myMutableTestArray` is fine. There are all objects inside the array. But leaving this method the instance variable `mutableTestArray` is empty.

So, where is the problem? Anyone an idea?
Note: I know I can access the instance variable with `self.mutableTestArray` and then everything will be okay, instead using it as a parameter, but I want to know what's wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters are passed by value in Objective-C.  Thus, you are creating a copy of a pointer to the object and passing that into the method.  When you do `myParam = ... new object ...;` that resets the copy to point to a new location, but has no effect on the original copy in the caller.

(To reiterate -- you are *copying the pointer*, not *copying the object*.)

To solve, declare your test method as returning an object:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)aTestMethod;
```

Then, you can simply:

```
self.mutableTestArray = [whateverObject aTestMethod];
```

(Since you aren't actually using the value passed in in the first place, there is no need for a parameter at all).

Comment: I can not do this, because in my real code, I have to pass several mutable and immutable arrays, I only did an example, otherwise the overview could be lost.

Comment: You'll need to add a more complete example. There are a number of possible solutions.  Personally, anytime I see "multiple related return values" it begs for a simple class whose instances can encapsulate said related values.

Answer (score 2):

By your command

```
myMutableTestArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
```

you are creating **new** allocation of mutableTestArray. So passing mutableTestArray as parameter to aTestMethod:

```
[self aTestMethod:self.mutableTestArray];
```

is useless because you override its value immediately when create this array inside your aTestMethod.

Try to create your array before passing it to your method (where you will fill it with data).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that parameters are transmitted by value, so in aTestMethod: you are modifying not the original pointer but a copy of it!
For this to work, you should pass the address of the pointer as in

```
self aTestMethod:&(self.mutableArray)
```

then the prototype of the method should be

```
-(void)aTestMethod:(NSMutableArray **)myArray
```

and in the code of it you should used *myArray as in

```
*myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Yours, JB

Comment: Pass-by-reference should never be used in Objective-C save for the most exceptionally rare cases.  This isn't one.  By definition using pass-by-reference is unnecessary when the method returns `(void)`.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason not to use pass-by-reference. I agree that in that case I may not be considered as necessary, but in a more general context, it could be used

Comment: I get in the line `self aTestMethod:&(self.mutableArray)` the error "address of property expression requested" if I put a `&` in front of it.

Comment: Pass-by-reference is *not* used across the frameworks; it is not a part of the standard API patterns of the system (and making your APIs look/feel like the system's is a boon to consistency and maintainability).  It is error prone and pass-by-reference of an instance variable breaks encapsulation.  The *only* two uses of pass-by-reference are the `NSError**` pattern and multiple return values (which are really the same thing).  In the multiple return value case, it almost always indicates that your API design should be revisited.

Comment: Not to mention that your code is wrong for exactly the reason @Tim pointed out;  `self.mutableArray` is a method call and cannot be used in a pass-by-reference context.

Comment: Okay, I see, I should avoid this what I am trying to do. But only to know, how can this be done, so it will work?

Comment: You would need to pass the address of the ivar directly;  something like `mutableTestArray` without the `self.`.  (I say "something like" because there may be certain compilers or situations under which that won't work -- it certainly will trip up the garbage collector on Mac OS X, in some configurations).